# How do I compute the limit of this product without delving into epsilon theorems?

Tags: calculus, limits

So, basically, those few lasts I've been struggling to compute the limit of a product without having to delve into epsilon stuff, that is:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i = 2}^n (2 - \sqrt[i]2)$$

What I've observed that it does not work with ratio test (it is inconclusive), Stolz-Cesaro cannot work and so do not most of the classical theorems, which made me think it works with Squeeze Theorem, as I just have to find two majorants.

That made me think of a problem I saw earlier this year, which was $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i = 2}^n (2 - \sqrt[i]e)$$ which was solvable by saying that $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n < e < (1 + \frac{1}{n-1})^n (1) $, or something along those lines. I've tried raising it to the power $ \ln{2} $, but it is not solvable afterwards as we get something ugly. Can someone give me a hint or something? Thank you.

P.S.: I've thought of using Taylor Series as well, but I'm not sure how that would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that : $\sqrt[i]{2}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{i}\right)=1+\frac{\ln(2)}{i}+o(\frac{1}{i})$ because $\frac{\ln(2)}{i}\to_{i\to\infty} 0$.

Therefore $2-\sqrt[i]{2}=1-\frac{\ln(2)}{i}+o(\frac{1}{i})$ and $\ln(2-\sqrt[i]{2})=\ln(1-\frac{\ln(2)}{i}+o(\frac{1}{i}))\sim_{i\to\infty} -\frac{\ln(2)}{i}$.

This implies $\sum_{i=2}^{n}\ln(2-\sqrt[i]{2}) \to_{n\to\infty}-\infty$ and passing to the exponential, $\prod_{i=2}^{n}(2-\sqrt[i]{2}) \to 0$.

Comment: Got it! However, is there any solution which does not involve approximation using Taylor's? Edit: imagine it as a problem for high-schoolers olympiad

Comment: In that case, one could try to show first that for all $i\ge  2$, $ (1+\frac{\ln(2)}{i})^i\le 2\le (1+\frac{\ln(2)}{i-1})^i$.